# null pointer loading data android java

Tags: android

I get a null pointer using load in android.

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Can anyone help me as to why. There are 4 houses so 'count' is read correctly.

```
        public void save() {
     try {
        OutputStream fos = openFileOutput("file.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeInt(data.getItems().size());
        for (int i = 0; i< data.getItems().size(); i++) {
        oos.writeObject(data.getItems().get(i)); 
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }


            public ArrayList<House> load() {
        Log.i("Read File", " Loading file ");
        FileInputStream fis;
        ArrayList<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();
        try {
            fis = openFileInput("file.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            int count = ois.readInt();
            for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
                try {
                    houses.add(i, (House) ois.readObject());
                    // or houses.add((House) ois.readObject()); - same error
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ois.close();
            return houses;  
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("Read", ""+e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Read", ""+e);
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: replace **houses.add(count, (House) ois.readObject());** with **houses.add((House) ois.readObject());** and check what happens...

Comment: I get the same error:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: You did't post full code then...

Comment: I posted both methods? getItems just returns an arrayList

Answer (score 2):

You create list houses, its size iz 0. after that you try to store something at position count - thats the problem.
Try

```
        ....
        int count = ois.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           houses.add((House) ois.readObject());
        }
        ....
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
houses.add(count, (House) ois.readObject());
```

`houses` is of size 0 at the beginning, and you try to insert to index 4 (count). should probably be:

```
houses.add((House) ois.readObject());
```

Comment: oh yea, xD. Sorry. I have changed the code above, but even if I remove that bit I still get the error just calling ois.readObject());

Comment: Same error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Answer (score 1):

instead of 
`houses.add(count, (House) ois.readObject());`
use 
`houses.add(i, (House) ois.readObject());`

Comment: Ou...yes..[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9925522/1298357) is the best solution in this cse

Comment: This is not totally right since a **FileNotFoundException** in forLoop can cause another **indexOutOfBoundException** ..